# If a woman, whose husband is away, becomes pregnant, is she assumed to be adulterous?

Tags: halacha, travel, arayot

If a woman's husband is away (e.g. for more than 9 months) and she is found to be pregnant (e.g. Tamar & Yehudah), is that sufficient grounds to declare that infidelity occurred?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This was already discussed in שולחן ערוך אבן העזר ד סעיף יד

> האשה שהיה בעלה במדינת הים ושהה שם יותר מי"ב חדש וילדה אחר י"ב חדש,
>   הולד ממזר, שאין הולד שוהה במעי אמו יותר מי"ב חדש. ויש מי שאומר שאינו
>   בחזקת ממזר. וכיון דפלוגתא הוא, הוי ספק ממזר:
>
> הגה: אבל תוך י"ב חדש אין לחוש, דאמרינן דאשתהי כל כך במעי אמו (מהרי"ק).
>   דוקא שלא ראו בה דבר מכוער, אבל אם ראו בה דבר מכוער לא אמרינן דאשתהי כל כך, וחיישינן ליה.
>       אשה שנתעברה מבעלה סוף סיון, וילדה תחילת כסליו, אף על פי שאין ביניהן רק חמשה חדשים, לא חיישינן לבנה לומר שהיתה מעוברת קודם לכן,
>   דהחדשים גורמים (עיין לקמן סימן קנ"ו סעיף ד') והוה ליה בן ז' (בתשובת
>   ר"י מינץ סימן ו'). ואפילו הפילה בתשרי, ושמעה הולד בוכה, לא חיישינן
>   שהיתה מעוברת קודם לכן, דאפשר לו לבכות לחמשה חדשים, אלא שהוא נפל ואינו
>   ראוי להיות קיים (בבית יוסף בשם תשובה שכך השיב הר"ד דוראן) (הובא בסוף
>   הטור סימן קעח):

There are many details regarding this issue. You may take a look at the Shach and Ta"Z there or look at the Aruch HaShulchan on this topic.

It looks like the limit is 12 months. If a child was born within 12 months of his mother's husband's absence, the child is assumed to *not* be a mamzer. If a child was born beyond 12 months of his mother's husband's absence, the child is assumed to be a mamzer.

I am not a posek; but, nowadays when nearly any location is accessible with a plane in 1-2 days, we may say that the husband returned with a plane and that no one knew about it.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. You may consider helping our Hebraically-challenged users by translating the Shulhhan 'Arukh's pesaq. Looking forward to more content from you.

Comment: @Lee  - +1 for "Hebraically-challenged"

Comment: One of my favorite things about this site is learning all kinds of new Hebrew words.  Today's new words:  mamzer and posek.

Comment: @WadCheber [This is the (ever incomplete) glossary.](http://meta.judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/581/mi-yodeya-glossary)

Comment: @Mike - that's a handy reference tool.  However, I tend to learn more readily if I can do the footwork myself.  If I look things up myself, I will usually retain the information better.